# cPanel generated passwords - doaddpop.html for SSL

Tags: php, email, cpanel

When a user creates an account I want to be able to automatically generate an email account for them with their username@domain.com similar to this:

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/51470/automatic-email-creation-in-cpanel-php

Creating a http request similar to this:

http://[example.com]:[2082]/frontend/[x]/mail/doaddpop.html?email=[test]&domain=[example.com]&password=[test]&quota=[10]

however, the site that I am working with has SSL (https / port 2083). In the post listed above they stated that it would be very difficult to make it work with SSL but this was back in 2005. I can't seem to find any information on SSL work arounds if there even are any.

Anybody encountered this and has a solution they can point me towards? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why SSL would cause issues unless the certificate was not trusted/expired/invalided and a certificate warning was presented when you visited the cPanel interface.

Comment: This is the issue. I get a certificate error. I'm not an SSL expert and not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my complete guide to do this and it actually works on my shared plan:

http://aftermanict.blogspot.it/2015/01/bash-cpanel-hostmonster-bluehost-email.html